# How to style a word inside a string that is being retrieved from firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, firebase-realtime-database

I have these values being retrieved from firebase. It looks like this

`Progress : lowback:1:0:12-8-2019 -- 8:21:57 PM:VAS:10 -- difficulty:-1 -- 1:12-8-2019 -- 8:22:28 PM:VAS:10 -- difficulty:-1 -- 2:12-8-2019 -- 8:22:56 PM:VAS:10 -- difficulty:-1 -- 3:12-8-2019 -- 8:25:52 PM:VAS:10 -- difficulty:-1 -- 4:12-8-2019 -- 8:27:10 PM:VAS:10 -- difficulty:-1`

Notice the word difficulty occurs too many times in the string. that is a textContent property of a DOM element. which is an h6.

How can i make the word difficulty a bold word. it doesn't have a span or any html tag which i can use to select it using `getElementById`.

```
var progressText = childSnapshot.child("userProfile/progress");
var StringifiedProgressText = JSON.stringify(progressText);

var progress = document.createElement("h6");

progress.textContent = "Progress : " + StringifiedProgressText;
progress.textContent = progress.textContent.replace(/{/g, "");
progress.textContent = progress.textContent.replace(/}/g, "");
progress.textContent = progress.textContent.replace(/"/g, "");
progress.textContent = progress.textContent.replace(/,/g, " -- ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to use .innerHTML property instead of .textContent? If yes, you can do the next:

```
.....
let temp = "Progress : " + StringifiedProgressText;
temp = temp.replace(/{/g, "");
temp = temp.replace(/}/g, "");
temp = temp.replace(/"/g, "");
temp = temp.replace(/,/g, " -- ");

progressTextBold = temp.replace(/difficulty/g, "<b>difficulty</b>");

progress.innerHTML = progressTextBold;
```